# All radio buttons are grouped together for all the items in the model list

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using MVC5

Situation:
my view iterates through a list of Person class where the properties are as follow:

```
int Id
string Name
string City
string ChosenText
List<string> SomeTextList
```

This list of string would be randomly generated strings.

while iterating through the list all the SomeTextList should be shown as radio button. Hence for every person all there are:

- one textbox for name
- one textbox for City
- group of radio button for SomeTextList

The code is :

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Name) 
    @foreach (var ans in item.SomeTextList)
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.ChosenText, "ans")@Html.Label(ans)
    }
}
```

Issue:
For all the persons the radio buttons as one group, i.e., I can select only one free text radio button from all the person list.

Goal:
For every Person I should be able to select one radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `for` loop to generate controls in a collection (not a `foreach` loop which generates duplicate `name` and `ID` attributes and would not post back to a collection)

Because every radio button you are generating the same name attribute `<input type="radio" name="ChosenText" ... />` they all belong to the same group allowing only one to be selected.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Name)
  <br />
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].City) 
  @foreach (var ans in Model[i].SomeTextList)
  {
    <label>
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].ChosenText, ans)
      <span>@ans</span>
    </label>
  }
}
```

This will generate (for the radio buttons)

```
<input type="radio" name="[0].ChosenText" value="abc" />
<input type="radio" name="[0].ChosenText" value="xyz" />
.....
<input type="radio" name="[1].ChosenText" value="abc" />
<input type="radio" name="[1].ChosenText" value="xyz" />
```

Comment: Edited answer to add a bit more explanation for you :)